# ASP.NET core web api "the name view does not exist in current context"

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I am building an asp.net core web api project.I am trying to add a search query through the following code. However, I am getting an error at the "view" that "the name view does not exist in current context".

```
//https://localhost:44354/api/comments?searchString=Agree
        [HttpGet("{searchString}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string searchString) 
        {
            var comments = from c in _context.Comments
                           select c;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                comments = comments.Where(s => s.Comments_content.Contains(searchString));
            }
            return View(await comments.ToListAsync());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an api. You are returning a response not a view. You should return this instead

```
return Ok(await comments.ToListAsync());
```

Besides, if this was a web project you need to have the corresponding view, `Index` created in your Views folder. For example if your controller name is `Blog`. Then the `Index` view should be in this path `Views/Blog/Index.cshtml`